# Build new dictionary from list of dictionary based on same key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to group up dicts based on same value of `categoryName` key.

Source of list dictionary

```
data = [{'category_id': 1,
  'categoryName': 'Civil',
  'author': 'x',
  'title': 'Stone'},
 {'category_id': 1,
  'categoryName': 'Civil',
  'author': 'y',
  'title': 'House'},
 {'category_id': 2,
  'categoryName': 'Programming',
  'author': 'x',
  'title': 'Python'},
 {'category_id': 2,
  'categoryName': 'Programming',
  'author': 'y',
  'title': 'Java'}]
```

My target output

```
new_data = {'Civil':[{'Title':'Stone', 'author':'x'},
                   {'Title':'House', 'author':'y'}],
         'Programming':[{'Title':'Python', 'author':'x'},
                       {'Title':'Java', 'author':'y'}]}
```

My attempts so far:

Build list of categoryName with

```
categories = set([i['categoryName'] for i in data])
```

Then build the new dict with

```
d = {}
for cat in categories:
    d[cat] = []
    for book in data:
        if book['category_name'] == cat:
            d[cat].append(book)
```

It works. But I don't think this is the right or elegant way to do it.

Looking for more solutions. Thanks!

Comment: what have you tried to do yourself before asking?

Comment: As @depperm said, show us your code first, but also, look up `defaultdict` it will really help you out here.

Comment: @depperm Hi, sorry, forgot to add my own attempts. I have edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to get details from each element of `data` I'd skip the `set` step and iterate over each list element to grab the title and author. If the category is in `new_data` append to the list otherwise add a new list with the information required.

```
data = [{'category_id': 1,
  'categoryName': 'Civil',
  'author': 'x',
  'title': 'Stone'},
 {'category_id': 1,
  'categoryName': 'Civil',
  'author': 'y',
  'title': 'House'},
 {'category_id': 2,
  'categoryName': 'Programming',
  'author': 'x',
  'title': 'Python'},
 {'category_id': 2,
  'categoryName': 'Programming',
  'author': 'y',
  'title': 'Java'}]

new_data={}
for d in data:
  if d['categoryName'] in new_data:
    new_data[d['categoryName']].append({'Title':d['title'],'author':d['author']}) 
  else:
    new_data[d['categoryName']]=[{'Title':d['title'],'author':d['author']}]

print(new_data)
#{'Civil': [{'Title': 'Stone', 'author': 'x'}, {'Title': 'House', 'author': 'y'}], 'Programming': [{'Title': 'Python', 'author': 'x'}, {'Title': 'Java', 'author': 'y'}]}
```